# Refresh ListView item on property changed

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a listView like this :

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="itemsListView" 
          BorderBrush="White" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ActualItem}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.STATUS}">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <local:StatusElement State="{Binding Path=Status,Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                Height="20"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>

            <GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static p:Resources.NAME}"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name,Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

It binds a list of items named `Items` with many fields. A thread parse the items and update the fields when it finishes. I call method `OnPropertyChanged` when fields are updated. It works fine for all fields except the one using my UserControl `local:StatusElement`. I've try to display my STATUS like the NAME, it's refreshes correctly but with `local:StatusElement` there is no refresh. breakpoints on get/set for StatusElement.State are never reached.

My userControl :

```
<UserControl ...
             x:Name="mainControl">
    <Grid Name="LabelGrid">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Grid.Column="0" Name="MyImage"
               Source="{Binding Source, Source={StaticResource MyImage}}"
               Width="{Binding Height, ElementName=mainControl}"
               Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=mainControl}"/>
        <Label Grid.Column="1" Name="statusLabel"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and:

```
public partial class StatusElement : UserControl
{

    // Dependency property backing variables
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("State",
                 typeof(String), typeof(StatusElement), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    private string _state = "";
    public String State
    {
        get
        {
            return _state;
        }
        set
        {
            _state = value;
            RefreshState();
        }
    }

    private void RefreshState()
    {
        switch (State)
        {
            case "":
                MyImage.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                break;
            default:
                MyImage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                break;
        }
        statusLabel.Content = State;
    }

    public StatusElement()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        RefreshState();
    }
}
```

Why the Content of my statusLabel doesn't refresh ?

Comment: Just a note, `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` has no effect in a one-way binding (as there is no data flow from target to source). Besides that, it is usually redundant to explicitly set `Mode=OneWay`, as this is already the default for most dependency properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition of the `State` dependency property is wrong.

It has to look like shown below, where the CLR property wrapper must call the `GetValue` and `SetValue` methods of the DependencyObject that owns the property.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty StateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
     "State",
     typeof(string),
     typeof(StatusElement),
     new PropertyMetadata(null, (o, e) => ((StatusElement)o).RefreshState()));

public string State
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(StateProperty); }
    set { SetValue(StateProperty, value); }
}
```

Note the second argument to the `PropertyMetadata` constructor. It is a static `PropertyChangedCallback`, implemented as lambda expression.

Answer (score 1):

Your class doesnt implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event. Implement it for the update to happen.

> Notifies clients that a property value has changed.

```
public partial class StatusElement : UserControl,INotifyPropertyChanged
{
 ....

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void RefreshState([CallerMemberName]string prop = "")
{
    switch (State)
    {
        case "":
            MyImage.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            break;
        default:
            MyImage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            break;
    }
    statusLabel.Content = State;
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));

    }
}
}
```

Comment: There is usually no need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in a UserControl, because properties are typically defined as dependency properties, which already have a built-in change notification mechanism.

Comment: Is there a tutorial i can view for this?

Comment: Google "wpf custom dependency properties".

Comment: I've try this but there is not change.
My problem is that when the status change on an item in my list `Items` (ObservableCollection<Item>) it doesn't update the value on `StatusElement`. I mean, I defined a breakpoint on `public String State {set ...}` and when value changes for `Item.Status` the code don't execute the set